# cp not working for source variable with file path having spaces

Tags: shell, escaping, filenames, quotes, spaces

I want to copy everything from a source directory (directory name contains spaces) to a destination.

The output of the `ls -l` command inside my working directory is as below:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr  5 06:39  destination
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr  5 06:08 'source directory with spaces'
```

When I do - `cp -r ./source\ directory\ with\ spaces/. destination/` the command works perfectly well and files (A.txt, B.txt & C.txt) inside the 'source directory with spaces' folder are copied successfully.

I want to making it dynamic, so I store the source location in a variable as -

`fileVar="./source\ directory\ with\ spaces/."`

Now when I hit the cp command using either of the below command:

```
cp -r $fileVar destination/
```

Error:

```
cp: cannot stat './source\': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'directory\': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'with\': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'spaces/A.txt': No such file or directory
```

OR

```
cp -r "$fileVar" destination/
```

Error:

```
cp: cannot stat './source\ directory\ with\ spaces/A.txt': No such file or directory
```

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: With quotes use: `fileVar="./source directory with spaces/"`

Comment: @anubhava - Doesn't work.